# SwiftUI - Disabling a button within a confirmationDialog

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am attempting to add a confirmationDialog which would/could contain 2 buttons.  Depending on certain conditions, one of the buttons would NOT be enabled but it appears for some reason if I set any of the buttons with .isDisabled(true) the button just will not show at all in the dialog.

I have searched high and low and cannot find an example where someone does this.  I do know I could probably write some hack where I create my own View with the buttons and show that, but I would have thought this would be available.  Does anyone know if this is even possible?

```
.confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showDialog, actions: {
            Button(LocalString.ok.localized, role: .destructive, action: {}).disabled(false)
            Button(LocalString.notOk.localized, role: .destructive, action: {}).disabled(true)
            Button(LocalString.cancel.localized, role: .cancel) {}
    })
```

In the above code, when dialog is shown, the OK and Cancel show.  The NotOk does not show at all.

Comment: Looks like swift ui just won't render disabled buttons. To flip the question around, why would you show an option you can't interact with? You could either be fine with the fact it isn't there, include some text in the confirmation dialog title explaining the condition if it would be disabled, or show the button enabled but provide feedback as to why the user can't do that action if they can't and press it. It is strange that it works this way though...

Comment: Thx Andrew.  This is more or less what I had told our UX Dept but they still wanted to see if it could be done.